# cannot retrieve data from lookup column

Tags: client-object-model

I'm trying to retrieve a lookup field using :

```
var lookup = ($(this).attr("ows_shARePublishTo_x003a_shAReSiteUR"));
```

Other columns seem to work fine, including another lookup column

The column name is:

```
Field=shARePublishTo%5Fx003a%5FshAReSiteUR
```

But keep getting undefined when I alert lookup. it seemed to work fine before I added and removed column from Library and Content Type.

Any ideas?

Most of code:

```
        var sliderList = "shARe Applications"; // Name of the list that contains slides
        var ListContentField = "shAReAppDesc"; //Internal Name of the Rich text field that has slide content      

        var ListBackgroundImageField = "shARe_x0020_Application_x0020_Ic"; //Internal Name of the picture field to use as background image


        var ListTitle="Title";
        var ListLink = "shAReAppURL";


        var thisSite = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();
        var siteURL = thisSite + "/SRE";
        var build = new String();

          //query to retrieve all items
          var query = "<Query><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'></Value></Neq></Where></Query>";


            $().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: true,
                webURL: siteURL,

                listName: sliderList,
 //                 CAMLViewFields: camlViewFields ,


                CAMLQuery: query,
                completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                   $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

                    var slideTitle = ($(this).attr("ows_"+ListTitle));
                    var slideLink = ($(this).attr("ows_"+ListLink));
                    var slideContent = ($(this).attr("ows_"+ListContentField));



                    var picture = $(this).attr("ows_"+ListBackgroundImageField);

                    var filename = picture.substr((picture.lastIndexOf("/")+1),(picture.length)); 
                    var thisSite = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();
                    var DynamicImageUrl= thisSite+"/SRE/shAReApplicationImages/"+filename;




                    var link = slideLink.split(",")[0];
                    var linkText = slideLink.split(",")[1];



                    //var lookup = ($(this).attr("ows_shARePublishTo_x003A_shARe_x0020"));
                    //display names  !!!
                    var lookup = ($(this).attr("ows_shARePublishTo_x003a_shAReSiteUR"));
                    alert(lookup);
                    //var lookup = lookup +";";


                var lookupArray = lookup.split(";");
                    // get top location, as iFrame used location unknown unless top used.
                    var TopPath = (window.top.location.pathname).toLowerCase();


                     for(var i = 0; i < lookupArray.length; i++){
                    // alert (lookupArray[i]);
                      var SingleItem = lookupArray[i].toLowerCase();
                      var PublishTo=  SingleItem.substr(SingleItem.lastIndexOf("sites")-1,SingleItem.length); 


                        var TopPath1 =  TopPath.substr(0,(TopPath.lastIndexOf("sitepages")-1));
                        //alert ("URLTopFrame-"+TopPath1);

                        if (PublishTo == TopPath1)
                        {
                        //alert (slideTitle + "match");

                        $(".carousel").append("<ul style=\"background:#FFFFFF;\"><img src="+ DynamicImageUrl +" style=\"width:35%; height:50%;\"   /><span id =\"title\">" + slideTitle+    "</span><BR /><BR /> <div id = \"BodyText\">"+slideContent+ "<BR /><a target= \"_top\" href=\" "+link +" \"> "+ linkText +"</a> "+ "</div>" +"</ul>");





                        }



                     } //end lookup array




                    }); // end for each function
```

Comment: Can you post the code on how `$(this)` is getting initialized? Have you Included that columns as part of `context.load`?

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: Is the lookup a required field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly request for the field using `CAMLViewFields` property. Something like

```
var CAMLViewFields = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='shARePublishTo_x003a_shAReSiteUR'/>" +
    "</ViewFields>"
```

And use this in

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: true,
    webURL: siteURL,
    listName: sliderList,
    CAMLViewFields: CAMLViewFields,
    ...
```

Comment: Hi That's worked I also had to add the other lookup in viewfields otherwise error occured (shARe_x0020_Application_x0020_Ic), Why did it work before, was it beacuse I have to add the coloumn in the default view?

Comment: Yes. Also by default required fields also get included